# Apache Kafka Streams building and starting jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to program a little test program for Apache Kafka Streams. What I've done so far was:

- Install Intellij.
- Copy the source code from git.
- Run `gradle wrapper` and `gradle idea` in the unziped folder.
- Import the folder in Intellij.
- Create new java class under streams/examples/src/main/java/... .
- Run `gradlew jar`
- Copy the .jar file in examples/build/libs/... to the server.

Now I want to run it. I've tried `java -cp kafka.jar *Class*`

But, all I've got was this exception:

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/ValueMapper
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Does somebody know what I've done wrong? I need some proper instructions.

Comment: You might want to look at the Kafka Streams examples under https://github.com/confluentinc/examples (folder `kafka-streams`).  There are several demo applications and end-to-end integration tests (which spawn embedded Kafka clusters so you don't need to install anything in that case).  You can use these examples not only to understand the setup -- including your build setup (cf. `kafka-streams/pom.xml`) -- but also as templates to create your own apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can just run your application within IntelliJ -- there is no need to assemble a jar and to copy this jar to any server.

> Copy the .jar file in examples/build/libs/... to the server.

What do you mean by "server"? If you refer to brokers, than this is not required. You can run you application anywhere you like. It is not required (and not recommended) to run your Streams application on the same servers as your brokers.

Furthermore, there is no reason to download the whole Kafka source code (or course you need the binaries for start up the brokers, but if you have already a Kafka cluster deployed you can skip this). A better way is to just start a new empty project and just add the dependency to `kafka-streams` (as you would do for any other library you want to use in your project).

The out this quickstart guide: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html

You can also check-out this examples:
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.1.x/kafka-streams